# How to create unique legend/color label for multiple variables and plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a multiple plot page in order to compare multiple variables within disease variables and patient status (i.e. deceased or recovered) over time.

Here's my code

```
p1 <- g + geom_smooth(data = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos, aes(x = days, y = sofa_score, color = outcome, group = outcome)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos$days) 

+ geom_smooth(data = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos, aes(x = days, y = resp_score, color = outcome, group = outcome)) + values = c("blue", "red")) + labs(x="Days after admission")

p2 <- g + geom_smooth(data = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos, aes(x = days, y = sofa_score, color = outcome, group = outcome)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos$days) 

+ geom_smooth(data = sofa_vivo_vs_mortos, aes(x = days, y = coag_score, color = outcome, group = outcome)) + labs(x="Days after admission")

ggarrange(p1, p2, labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 2)
```

Which yields the following plot:

[image]

Since it's not distinguishable which variable is which on the plots, I would like my code to yield:

1-A unique legend location for the whole page

2-A color legend for each variable not based only on it's grouping variable (in my code, the `outcome` variable), but also on the name of the variable itself (i.e. one colour + legend for `sofa_score` variable in which `outcome = deceased` and another for `sofa_score` in which `outcome = recovered`, combined in the same plot as the second variable under analysis (i.e. variable `resp_score` with same `outcome` stratification)

Similar desired result:
[image: Please notice how there are 4 lines in each plot, 2 for each variable, 1 for each outcome within the variable]

Edit for sample data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,32, by=1), sofa_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE),  resp_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE), 
outcome = c('deceased', 'recovered'), 
days = sample(1:20, 32, replace = TRUE), coag_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Could you generate some dummy data with the same variable names and vector classes as your real data for us to play around with?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Sure thing. I have just edited the post with it and here it goes:

```df2 <- data.frame(ID = seq(1,32, by=1), sofa_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE),  resp_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE), outcome = c('deceased', 'recovered'), days = sample(1:20, 32, replace = TRUE), coag_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE))```

Answer (score 1):

I generally find that the patchwork package is great for plot composition, including collecting the legends from multiple plots. An example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(42)

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = seq(1,32, by=1), 
  sofa_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE),  
  resp_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE), 
  outcome = c('deceased', 'recovered'), 
  days = sample(1:20, 32, replace = TRUE), 
  coag_score = sample(1:8, 8, replace = TRUE)
)

p1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(days)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = coag_score, colour = outcome, group = outcome)) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("tomato", "dodgerblue"),
    name = "Coag Score"
  )

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(days)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = resp_score, colour = outcome, group = outcome)) +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("limegreen", "orchid"),
    name = "Resp Score"
  )

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The exact plot I'm looking for its one in which you can merge both ```Coag``` and ```Resp Score``` plots into one with different colours for each line, though, because I want to compare two variables in two different states i.e. 4 different lines.